# How to Compile and Link an OpenGL/GLFW Program with Cygwin on Windows?

Tags: windows, opengl, g++, cygwin, glfw

I struggled with finding documentation on compiling a basic OpenGL/GLFW example Windows using Cygwin-g++ so I decided to post an answer to my own question.

- OS: Windows (10)
- Compiler: Cygwin g++ (x86_64-pc-cygwin)
- Code: [GLFW Documentation's Example Code](https://www.glfw.org/documentation.html) (basic working example shown below. Won't create a window but should output text if everything builds/links correctly):

```
    #define GLFW_DLL
    #include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
    #include <iostream>
    
    int main(void) {
        std::cout << "Code works" << std::endl;
        if (!glfwInit())
            return -1;
        glfwTerminate();
        return 0;
    }
```

- Compilation: `g++ -Wall -Iinclude main.cpp -o main.exe -L<folder glfw3.dll is in> -lglfw3 -lopengl32 -lgdi32`

**Issues**

- Code would compile and build but no output window would appear
- My current linking is fine, but different combinations would result in `undefined reference` errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

alternative solution building the GLFW for Cygwin

Download glfw-3.3.4.zip and then

```
$ unzip glfw-3.3.4.zip
$ cd glfw-3.3.4
$ ccmake .
```

set BUILD_SHARED_LIBS to ON. Configure and generate

```
$ make
$ make install

Install the project...
-- Install configuration: ""
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/GLFW
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/GLFW/glfw3.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/GLFW/glfw3native.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib/cmake/glfw3/glfw3Config.cmake
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib/cmake/glfw3/glfw3ConfigVersion.cmake
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib/cmake/glfw3/glfw3Targets.cmake
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib/cmake/glfw3/glfw3Targets-noconfig.cmake
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/glfw3.pc
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib/libglfw.dll.a
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/bin/cygglfw-3.dll
```

So you will have a proper Cygwin build installed under `/usr/local`
after that, running under X server

```
$ g++ main.cpp -o main -lglfw -L/usr/local/lib

$ ./main.exe 
Code works
```

Comment: thanks! I was trying to use cmake to build from scratch but couldn't figure it out. If you've tried this out and are sure it works I'll select it as the answer.

Comment: All tested and verified. What problem have you with Cygwin cmake ?

Comment: Cygwin works fine. I'm just new to using CMake and make and didn't manage to get the libraries generated.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a summary of the solution from [University of Michigan's EECS 487 building OpenGL/GLFW Apps](http://web.eecs.umich.edu/%7Esugih/courses/eecs487/glfw-howto/)

**Install verification**
Check that these files are present under the cygwin64 directory.

- header files: /usr/include/w32api/GL
- static libraries: /lib/w32api/lib{opengl,gdi}32.a

**Install GLFW Binaries**
[GLFW Binaries](https://www.glfw.org/download.html)

**Copy Files from the GLFW Binaries into Cygwin**

- In `\cygwin64\usr\x86_64-pc-cygwin\` paste the include file from the GLFW binaries `include` file. You should have `\cygwin64\usr\x86_64-pc-cygwin\include\GLFW` with the .h files inside
- In `C:\cygwin64\usr\x86_64-pc-cygwin\lib` paste libglfw3.a and libglfw3dll.a from  the lib-mingw-w64 folder of the GLFW binaries
- In `\cygwin64\usr\x86_64-pc-cygwin\bin` paste `glfw3.dll` from the aforementioned folder
- Add `\cygwin64\usr\x86_64-pc-cygwin\bin` to PATH
- To compile `g++ -Wall -Iinclude main.cpp -o main.exe -LC:\cygwin64\usr\x86_64-pc-cygwin\bin -lglfw3 -lopengl32 -lgdi32` (change -L to wherever your cygwin is stored).

**Etc**

- The first link has instructions for building with the MingW toolchain specifically, as well as with Linux, MacOS, and Visual Studios